# Stop Iteration: While making extra column using next function in csv in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to make extra column in my csv file.For this I'm using next function but it is showing the following error.

```
vechainofficial_tweets.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 22, in <module>
    row=next(reader)
```

StopIteration

```
import csv
import os
import glob
from textblob import TextBlob

path=''
extension='csv'
os.chdir('./')
results=[i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

# print(result)

for result in results:
    print(result)
    with open(result,'r') as csvfile:
            with open(result,'w') as csv1:
                writer=csv.writer(csv1,lineterminator='\n')
                reader=csv.reader(csvfile)

                all=[]

                row=next(reader)
                row.append('Sentiment')
                all.append(row)

                for row in reader:
                    row.append(TextBlob(row[2]).sentiment)
                    all.append(row)
                writer.writerows(row)

                print("success")
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

A `StopIteration` error means that the `generator` you are calling `next()` on is empty. So, in your case, the `reader` generator is empty, so throws an error when you call `next(reader)`.

So to resolve this, you need to make sure that the file `result` is actually a `CSV` when opened.

You can do this quite simply by emitting the nested `with` statement and replacing it with simply `print(csvfile.read())` which will make the program print the contents of each `.csv` file.

Then it is just a matter of analysing the output to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you are trying to write to the file you are reading from. You code opens `result` twice, once for the reader and once for the writer. Text files don't work like that. You need to open one file for input and another file for output.

Secondly, `next()` doesn't add columns to your file. It moves to the next record of an input file. If you are using `csv`'s built-in iteration you need a very good reason to be using `next()` at all.